# Limit on the number of NPCs

Tags: unity-game-engine

Such an idea, for which I don't even have any ideas how to do it right. In general, the thought is:
There are, say, three NPCs on the stage (Conditionally), and there is also one building (Conditionally). Each NPC has its own task, but I do not know how to take an NPC who does not have a task and send one NPC to work in the building, and not several at once. Namely, each NPC has work statuses, and there is also a status 0, meaning that the NPC is not busy, there may be several such "free" ones, and if one is assigned the status of work - go to the building, then everyone who has this status will go, but how can we make sure that only one free NPC is taken and sent there?
I know the question is as incomprehensible and terrible as possible, but maybe someone will understand...

Comment: Tell the building which NPCs are working there -> building knows how many it has assigned already -> only requests a new worker if one is missing -> only picks ONE among the idle workers

Comment: @derHugo , I have exactly the same idea, but I don't understand how to take one and forbid the others to go there?

Comment: Well as soon as one already goes there there will be no free space anymore so why should another one go there? I would increase the number of workers as soon as one starts going there, not when he arrives ;)

Comment: @derHugo ,Okay, I'll ask a simpler question. How do I create a limit? I have ideas for implementation, but I want to hear the opinion of a more experienced person.

Comment: What do you mean `How do I create a limit`? You set an `int` value somewhere -> that's the maximum amount limit. You only request workers/allow workers to pick a building `if(currentWorkerAmount < maxWorkerAmount)` ...

Comment: @derHugo , Okay, let's see.

Comment: @derHugo , To be honest, I did not understand how to make the implementation, the problem of assigning the status of work to the NPC.

Comment: @derHugo , Even if one NPC comes to the place, the rest still go there, that is, I don't understand how to separate one of several NPCs.

Comment: It is really hard to tell without seeing your implementation of an NPC ...

Comment: @derHugo ,Okay, I'll figure it out myself somehow, I'll send you what happened later.

Comment: @derHugo ,how do I add GameObject to GameObject[]? I've tried everything and nothing comes out...

Comment: I don't know what you have tried .. but `yourArray[someIndex] = your object;` ? ... If you want to dynamically add more elements then you would rather want to go for a `List<GameObject>` and use `yourList.Add(someObject);`

Comment: @derHugo ,public List<GameObject[]> Testarray;
Testarray.Add(gameObject);
 I try, but I get the cs1503 error.

Comment: This is a list of arrays of objects ... is that really what you want?

Comment: @derHugo ,Yes, I want to add objects with status 0 to the list and already take these NPCs from the list. When their status 0 is removed, they are removed from the list. It seems to me that this option is more or less adequate in relation to My task.

Comment: Still this sounds like you want a list of objects `List<GameObject>` and not a list of arrays of objects `List<GameObject[]>` ...

Comment: @derHugo , I need a list of objects with status 0. case 0: Debug.Log(GameObject); break; This code shows a list of objects with this status, so how is it written to a sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made, so, to begin with, the code:

File WorkingPlace:

```
public static bool SignalFreeNPCPoint = false;
public static int WorkingPlaceNPC = 0;
public void ProductBoardNPC()
{
    SignalFreeNPCPoint = true;
    WorkingPlaceNPC += 1;
}
public void ProductBoard_Stop()
{
    WorkingPlaceNPC -= 1;
    SignalFreeNPCPoint = true;
}
```

This "ProductBoardNPC()" and "ProductBoard_Stop()" method's for button in Unity.

File NPCSctipt:

```
public List<GameObject> ListGM = new List<GameObject>(); 
public int TaskNumber = 0;
void Update()
{
    TaskManager();
    LogicNPC();
}
private void TaskManager()
{
    switch (TaskNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            //You code
            break;
        case 1:
            ListGM.Remove(gameObject);
            break;
        case 2:
            ListGM.Remove(gameObject);
            break;
        case 3:
            ListGM.Remove(gameObject);
            break;
        case 4:
            ListGM.Remove(gameObject);
            break;
    }
}
private void LogicNPC()
{
    if (WorkingPlace.SignalFreeNPCPoint == true)
    {
        if (TaskNumber == 0 & WorkingPlace.WorkingPlaceNPC == 1)
        {
            ListGM.Add(gameObject);
            TaskNumber = 4;
        }
        if (TaskNumber == 4 & WorkingPlace.WorkingPlaceNPC == 0)
        {
            TaskNumber = 0;
        }
        WorkingPlace.SignalFreeNPCPoint = false;
    }
}
```

How the code works:
When you click on the button, an NPC with the status 0 is searched, the last NPC with this status is taken and entered into the array, after which it is given a different status to perform "work", after which it is removed from the array to make room for another NPC.
In this case, the array is a buffer and is simply necessary. If you have better ideas than mine, I will be happy to listen)
The implementation is a clean bike made of crutches, but it works flawlessly. Yes, about FPS drawdowns, it doesn't seem to load the system much, if there are drawdowns, then write what to fix.

Comment: Your switch case is pretty redundant ... why not simply `if(TaskNumber == 0){ ... } else { ... }` ?

Comment: @derHugo ,"if else" does not suit me, at least because management goes for each individual taken NPC, although the list of statuses is common to all. You don't think I'm going to publish the full code with all the nested functions, do you?